# ctrl shift enter for array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that returns the estimated std dev for a portfolio to a cell. However, as the no of shares, their covar as well as their weights will change basically constantly and with the different portfolios i want this in VBA (my ultimate goal is to make my reporting as easy as possible).

I can't seem to understand the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, or the sqr part.

Could you please look at my code help me?

```
Sub PorteføljeRisiko()
Dim RapportBok As Workbook
Dim RapportArk As Worksheet
Set RapportBok = Workbooks("Rapport kunder")
Set RapportArk = RapportBok.Sheets(1)

Dim Region1 As Long
Dim RegionA As Long
Dim Matrise As Range
```

(as the no of shares vary, I here find out how many rows that actually include a value(i.e. % weighting in each share))

```
Region1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RapportArk.Range("AC7:AC18"), "<>" & "")
RegionA = Region1 - 1
```

(to get the matrix for the covar between shares as the no of shares change with puchase and sale of shares. the matrix starts in cells(3,55)

```
SisteKolonne = RapportArk.Cells(RegionA + 3, RegionA + 55)

Set Matrise = RapportArk.Range(Cells(3, 55), Cells(3 + RegionA, 55 + RegionA))

Set Region = RapportArk.Range("AC7:AC" & Region1 + 6)
```

(I want the result in Range("AG21"))

```
RapportArk.Range("AG21").FormulaArray = MMult(Application.MMult(Region, Matrise), Application.Transpose(Region))
```

(Everything works fine, except that it returns #VALUE! as i can't seem to get neither the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> part nor the SQR part in the macro)

```
End Sub
```

Comment: You aren't putting a formula anywhere, so `FormulaArray` and Ctrl+Shift+Enter don't apply. Why do you have two `MMult` calls there?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Rory. A.S.H. solved it for me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all what you are computing here in VBA is not a `formula` but a `value`. Apart of that, I could not verify all your calculations but I could see a problem here:

> `Application.MMult(Region, Matrise)`

The dimensions do not respect the rules of matrix multiplication. From analyzing your code, `Region` is a column vector with size `Region1`, while `Matrise` is a `Region1 x Region1` Matrix.

Remember that Matrix multiplication is not commutative. Most likely what you wanted is to switch the order of these operands:

```
Application.MMult(Matrise, Region)
```

This will give you a column vector of size `Region1`. But then you want to have a dot product with the vector `Region` and here again, the *row vector* should come first, so you should apply the `Transpose` on the first operand not on the second one. So the correct statement should be:

```
RapportArk.Range("AG21").value = _
    Application.MMult(Application.Transpose(Application.MMult(Matrise, Region)), Region)
```

Since the last operation is the `dot-product` of two vectors, you can probably simplify it using `SumProduct`:

```
RapportArk.Range("AG21").value = _
    Application.SumProduct(Application.MMult(Matrise, Region), Region)
```

Comment: That works brilliantly! I don't think you will ever understand just how grateful I am!!! :) Thank you!